# udev Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: debian

Since several weeks, I am not able to update/install anything on my Debian Jessie 8.7.
When I do apt-get upgrade (or install/remove any package), it errors out as below. 
Any help would be appreciated

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u7) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'lprng' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'lpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'cupsys' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and lprng if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service lprng at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping lprng depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping lpd depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping cupsys depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8402-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-cache policy returns the following :

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://www.scootersoftware.com/ bcompare4/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Scooter Software,a=stable,n=bcompare4,l=Scooter Software,c=non-free
     origin www.scootersoftware.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/  Packages
     release o=videolan,a=stable,n=stable,l=videolan,c=
     origin download.videolan.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Specifically, for `minidlna` and `lprng`:

```
root@Frederic:/home/frederic# apt-cache policy minidlna lprng
minidlna:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.2+dfsg-1.1+b3
  Version table:
     1.1.2+dfsg-1.1+b3 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
lprng:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.B-2
  Version table:
     3.8.B-2 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the information. The reason I was asking is that jessie, being stable, should not show such problems. So it's likely that some outside package is causing these problems.

Comment: It seems to me that udev is causing the issue (dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1). For some reason, it can't be configured !?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why `insserv` is being run at all. I don't recall seeing it run lately, though I have it installed. Isn't it associated with the old system of init scripts? But now we are in the Brave New World of Systemd.

Comment: `root@Frederic:/home/frederic# dpkg --purge minidlna lprng
(Reading database ... 187809 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing minidlna (1.1.2+dfsg-1.1+b3) ...
Purging configuration files for minidlna (1.1.2+dfsg-1.1+b3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'lprng' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'lpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'cupsys' missing LSB tags and overrides
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove lprng which isn't installed
root@Frederic:/home/frederic# `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minidlna` and `lprng` initscripts are causing the issues you’re seeing. Since they are no longer installed (as indicated by the output of `apt-cache policy`), you should just purge the packages — this will remove the initscripts which are no longer needed anyway:

```
dpkg --purge minidlna lprng
```

(The big problem with initscripts in this situation is that they no longer get upgraded, so they no longer receive bug fixes, but they’re still taken into account by the initscript dependency resolver.)